# Ellipsis on fluid widths

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a wrapper and i want to have the first div with max-width 65% and second div with max-width 35%, first is left aligned while second is right aligned, both on same row (white-space:nowrap), so basically what i'm trying to get is this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                         |                                           |
| THIS IS IS SHORT TEXT   |               NOW THIS LINE COULD BE LONG |
|                         |                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

now in worst case:

```
<----------------- 65% ---------------------->   <------ 35% -------->
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                              |                      |
| NOW THIS LINE IS LONG AND GROW MORE CAU...   | NOW THIS LINE COU... |
|                                              |                      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i need to show text-overflow ellipsis on both texts. Any ideas?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: max-width on both columns, white-space: nowrap on container, text-overflow: ellipsis on both divs

Comment: "*Any ideas?*" Use a table instead? Why does it need to be DIVs?

Comment: By the way, do you mean that the second column should have a **MIN** width of 35%? Because that's what the rest of your question would seem to suggest (particularly the diagram).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could just use a left-floated DIV:

(Note that the max-widths are for demo purposes only... you can allow these to flow to 100% and it should still work.)

```css
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.outer {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: right;
}

.inner1 {
  max-width: 65%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: left;
}

.inner2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate outer" style="max-width: 500px;">
  <div class="truncate inner1">
    THIS IS IS SHORT TEXT
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    NOW THIS LINE COULD BE LONG
  </div>
</div>

&nbsp;

<div class="truncate outer" style="max-width: 500px">
  <div class="truncate inner1">
    NOW THIS LINE IS LONG AND GROW MORE CAUTIOUS?
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    NOW THIS LINE COULD BE LONG
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks JDB, it works, but not valid, i must use TWO divs inside the wrapper, your example uses only one.

Comment: @FidoBoy - Yeah, sure, just wrap the rest of the content in a DIV and then set the display to "inline". No real difference there.

Comment: It doesn't work, in second line, the green column does not have text. Anyway i've ended solving it using flexboxes :)

Comment: @FidoBoy - Ahh... I see. It's broken in Safari. Interesting... but not surprising. Safari is very bad at correctly implementing web standards. That said, you need a universal fix, so totally understand that this isn't going to work for you.