# BFC is overlapped when designing three-column layout

Tags: html, css

```css
.left {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
}
.mid {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
}
.container {
  width:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="mid">midmidmidmidmidmidmidmid</div>
</div>
```

Like above, I want the mid part get auto-fit width and it will be a long text, just show '...'. 
I plan to use float to implement the three-column layout, and I learned that BFC will never be overlapped by other BFC, how does my right part get overlapped.?  Help thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you use flexbox to create your three-column layout?

Comment: Can someone tell me what *BFC* is?

Comment: @hungerstar I think he means [Block Formatting Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Comment: @Helenesh gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Flexbox to create your layout. This [resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can help you to get started with it. Using flexbox will also solve your 'overlapping' issue thanks to the property `flex-wrap: wrap`. [Play](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) around with it.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="mid">midmidmidmidmidmidmidmid</div>
</div>
```

In your case, your container is only allowed to be 100px wide, so it tries to fit everything in that small space. It's too small. Make your container larger, or use `min-width`.

Comment: I can use flexbox to do this, one reason is, the code before is using float to do this and I want to minimize changes, and when I'm trying using float and learn something about BFC, I found it really strange that the two blocks are overlapping... Thanks!

Comment: @Codoge That's because your container is only allowed to be 100px wide, so it tries to fit everything in that small space. It's too small.

Comment: I see... Is there any way I can avoid the overlap, just hide the mid part with '...' ?

Comment: Yes, by giving the container 500px (for example).

Comment: I mean, if I set the container long enough, definitely there will be no overlap, the issue here is, the container is not enough to container all the texts, so that I want to hide some of the mid part instead of overlapping with my right part

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388858/ellipsis-on-fluid-widths?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you arrived at, *"I learned that BFC will never be overlapped by other BFC."*

I'm going to use [MDN's Block Formatting Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) as a source.

Essentially, as far as floats are concerned, a new BFC will allow an element with floated descendants to *"see"* the whole element and not just the content of the element. When an element is floated it is taken out of the normal document flow.

The overlapping happens because of other properties that you have applied to your elements and not so much whether there's a new BFC. If I remove all the properties that are controlling what happens to the content of the `.mid` and `.container` elements, you'll get the order you want but the content of `.mid` is not on a single line.

The overlapping also happens because of `white-space: nowrap;` property on `.container` which forces the content of `.mid` to be on a single line which then overlaps the content of `.right`. Note that I added spaces to the text of `.mid` to illustrate that if the content is not too big, it will fit in the small space between `.left` and `.right`.

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mid {}
.container {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="mid">mid mid mid mid mid mid mid mid</div>
</div>
```

To get the desired result, add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.mid` instead of `.container` and remove `display: inline-block;`.

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.mid {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="mid">midmidmidmidmidmidmidmid</div>
</div>
```